# Copy two or more fields into one field in Solr

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I would like to copy multiple fields to one specific field in Solr.
My requirement is I want to display suggesstions from different fields available in managed schema.

I want to copy fields diseasearea, enrollmenttype, institutionname and title into field "text_suggest".

And then I want to show suggesstions from "text_suggest" field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use copy field for the same.

The name of the field you want to copy is the source, and the name of the copy is the destination. In `schema.xml`, it’s very simple to make copies of fields:

```
<copyField source="cat" dest="text" />

<field name="newdescription" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />


<copyField source="diseasearea" dest="newdescription"/>
<copyField source="enrollmenttype" dest="newdescription"/>
<copyField source="institutionname" dest="newdescription"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="newdescription"/>
```